# can i set touch to be the upper finger and touch 2 to be always the lower finger on the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, phonegap-build

how can i set the touch1 to be the upper finger on the screen and touch2 to be always the lower finger on the screen? even if the lower touch came first ?

```
  var touch1 = e.originalEvent.touches["0"];
  var touch2 = e.originalEvent.touches["1"];
```

can the two variables be swapped after each

i am asking this because phonegap has some problems in detecting the second touch on the screen when it is converted to android app

this is a demo of what i tried to convert [demo](http://jsbin.com/sowikuvaqe/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried checking the coordinates of the events?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this helps... additional event interrogation for more android and ios cross browser compat. If the lower coordinate is triggered first then swap the variable values (or that's the plan).

```
var touch1 = e.originalEvent.touches[0] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];
var touch2 = e.originalEvent.touches[1] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[1];

var touchX_1 = touch1.pageX || touch1.screenX, touchY_1 = touch1.pageY || touch1.screenY;
var touchX_2 = touch2.pageX || touch2.screenX, touchY_2 = touch2.pageY || touch2.screenY;

if (touchY_1 > touchY_2){ // is first touch lower than second touch ?
    var shimx = touchX_1, shimy = touchY_1; // create a temporary shim
  touchX_1 = touchX_2, touchY_1 = touchY_2; // copy the second touch coordinate to the first
  touchX_2 = shimx, touchY_2 = shimy; // put the lower touch coordinate into the upper
}

// now touchXY_2 is the higher touch position
```